Inverse Laplace transform does not give a soluton
I am trying to derive the inverse Laplace transform of the following Laplace transform:
$$
\mathcal{L}(d, \sigma; t) = \left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi  d}{2}\right) \left(\left(\sigma ^4 t^2-1\right)^{-d/2}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3-d}{2};\frac{1}{t^2 \sigma ^4}\right)}{\sigma ^2 t \Gamma
   \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}\right)\right){}^n
$$
Where the original function is defined as:
$$
f(d, \sigma; v) = 
\frac{2^{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{n}{2}} \sigma ^{-n-1} v^\frac{n - 1}{2} K_{\frac{ n - 1}{2}}\left(\frac{v}{\sigma ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} x \ge 0;
0, x < 0
$$
The Laplace transform above represents the n-th convolution of the function.
f[d_, \[Sigma]_] := Piecewise[{{(2^(3/2 - d/2)*v^((-1 + d)/2)*\[Sigma]^(-1 - d)*BesselK[(-1 + d)/2, v/\[Sigma]^2])/(Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[d/2]), v >= 0}}, 0]


laplaceFunc = 
     Assuming[{v >= 0, t >= 0}, 
      LaplaceTransform[f[d, \[Sigma]], v, t, 
       Assumptions -> {Element[v, Reals], v >= 0, \[Sigma] > 0, 
         Element[\[Sigma], Reals], Element[d, Integers], d >= 1}]]

laplaceFuncSimp = 
         FullSimplify[laplaceFunc^n, 
          Assumptions -> {Element[v, Reals], v >= 0, \[Sigma] > 0, 
            Element[\[Sigma], Reals], Element[n, Integers], n >= 1, 
            Element[d, Integers], d >= 1}]

generalizedLaplaceFuncSimp = 
         Assuming[{t >= 0, v >= 0, Element[v, Reals], v >= 0, \[Sigma] > 0, 
           Element[\[Sigma], Reals], Element[n, Integers], n >= 1} , 
          InverseLaplaceTransform[laplaceFuncSimp, t, v , 
           Assumptions -> {Element[v, Reals], v >= 0, \[Sigma] > 0, 
             Element[\[Sigma], Reals], Element[n, Integers], n >= 1, Element[d, Integers], d >= 1}]]

Sadly, Mathematica is unable to derive the inverse of this function. Mathematica can derive some inverse Laplace functions if I set $d= 2k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
Edit
Here is the distribution sampled for varying levels of $n$ and $d$:


Do you need a symbolic answer -- as opposed to a numerical inversion?

Yes I would like a symbolic answer.

"Yes I would like a symbolic answer". What for?

Personally, I prefer symbolic answers, so I would like to have that available, but, of course, I understand that it is not always possible to get such an answer.

"Personally, I prefer symbolic answers".  Is the complicated answer in terms of  a rare special function usefull?. BTW, it's a known fact Enrico Fermi used numerical integration instead of a complicated antiderivative in N-L formula.

I agree with you that Mariusz Iwaniuk's who's answers are in terms of a rare special function, while fascinating to look at, do not help me with my problem, as I cannot use them anyway.

The main reason for asking this question was to try to derive the expectation of the function listed in my "follow up" question , where from my limited stats understanding to compute expectation of the distribution that I want I would need to find the joint distribution of the numerator and the denominator given that they are dependent on each other due to the $w_i$ factor being present in both. From this I would need to find the PDF of both.

I technically know the answer to the expectation of the distribution in the question; however, I know that with the ratios, especially if the numerator and denominator are dependent on each other $E[X/Y] \neq E[X]/E[Y]$; however, in this case, $E[X/Y] = E[X]/E[Y]$ works for me. I am just trying to understand better why that is the case since I need to follow similar steps to derive the expectation of a more complicated system afterward. Since for that system $E[X/Y] \neq E[X]/E[Y]$ is indeed true.

Edited and Corrected
For general parameters: n,d symbolic (analytical) answer probably can't be found.
I have solution for: n=2.
$$\frac{(1+i) (2 i)^{-d} \sqrt{\pi } v^{-\frac{1}{2}+d} \sigma ^{-1-2 d} J_{-\frac{1}{2}+d}\left(\frac{i v}{\sigma ^2}\right) \sec ^2\left(\frac{d \pi }{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (d)}-\frac{\left(2 \sqrt{\pi } v^d \sigma ^{-2 (1+d)} \sec ^2\left(\frac{d \pi }{2}\right)\right) \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_m
   \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)_n (1)_m \left(\frac{v^2}{\sigma ^4 4}\right)^m \left(\frac{v^2}{\sigma ^4 4}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}\right)_m \left(\frac{1+d}{2}\right)_{m+n}
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1+d}{2}\right)_{m+n} n! m!}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3-d}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right) \Gamma (1+d)}+\frac{\left(\pi  v \sec ^2\left(\frac{d \pi
   }{2}\right)\right) \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_m \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n (1)_m (1)_n \left(\frac{v^2}{\sigma ^4 4}\right)^n
   \left(\frac{v^2}{\sigma ^4 4}\right)^m}{\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}\right)_m \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}\right)_n (1)_{m+n} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_{m+n} n! m!}}{\sigma ^4 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2}$$
Double infinite series can be expressed by Kampé de Fériet function, that's why Mathematica won't
compute Inverse Laplace Transform.
$\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_m \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)_n (1)_m \left(\frac{v^2}{\sigma ^4 4}\right)^m \left(\frac{v^2}{\sigma ^4
   4}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}\right)_m \left(\frac{1+d}{2}\right)_{m+n} \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1+d}{2}\right)_{m+n} n! m!}=\\\mathrm{F}^{0:1;2}_{2:0;1} 
\Bigg(
\begin{matrix}
  - & : & \frac{d}{2} & ;\frac{1}{2}, 1 & \\ 
 \frac{d+1}{2},\frac{d+1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & : & - & ; \frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2} &
\end{matrix}
\Bigg|
\frac{v^2}{4 \sigma ^4},\frac{v^2}{4 \sigma ^4}
\Bigg)
$
and
$\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_m \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n (1)_m (1)_n \left(\frac{v^2}{\sigma ^4 4}\right)^n \left(\frac{v^2}{\sigma ^4
   4}\right)^m}{\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}\right)_m \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}\right)_n (1)_{m+n} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_{m+n} n! m!}=\\\mathrm{F}^{0:2;2}_{2:1;1} 
\Bigg(
\begin{matrix}
  - & : & \frac{1}{2},1 & ;\frac{1}{2}, 1 & \\ 
 1, \frac{3}{2} & : & \frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2} & ; \frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2} &
\end{matrix}
\Bigg|
\frac{v^2}{4 \sigma ^4},\frac{v^2}{4 \sigma ^4}
\Bigg)$
I don't know if it's possible to simplify the Kampé de Fériet function more.
Maybe exist reduction formula on Internet you need to look for.
G1[d_, σ_, v_, M_] := ((1 + I)  (2  I)^-d  Sqrt[π]  
v^(-(1/2) + d)  σ^(-1 - 2  d)  BesselJ[-(1/2) + 
  d, (I  v)/σ^2]  Sec[(d  π)/2]^2)/
Gamma[d] - (2  Sqrt[π]  v^
  d  σ^(-2  (1 + d))  Sec[(d  π)/2]^2)/(Gamma[(3 -d)/
   2]  Gamma[d/2]  Gamma[1 + d])*
Sum[(Pochhammer[1/2, m]  Pochhammer[d/2, n]   Pochhammer[1, 
   m]  ((v^2/σ^4*4^-1)^m)*((v^2/σ^4*4^-1)^
    n))/(Pochhammer[3/2 - d/2, m]*Pochhammer[(1 + d)/2, m + n]*
  Pochhammer[1/2 + (1 + d)/2, m + n]*n!   m!), {m, 0, M}, {n, 0, 
 M}] + (π  v  Sec[(d  π)/2]^2)/(σ^4  Gamma[
   3/2 - d/2]^2  Gamma[d/2]^2)*
 Sum[(Pochhammer[1/2, m]   Pochhammer[1/2, n]   Pochhammer[1, 
   m]  Pochhammer[1, n]*(v^2/σ^4*4^-1)^
   n*(v^2/σ^4*4^-1)^m)/(Pochhammer[3/2 - d/2, 
   m]   Pochhammer[3/2 - d/2, n]*Pochhammer[1, m + n]*
  Pochhammer[3/2, m + n]*n!  m!), {m, 0, M}, {n, 0, M}]

Plot[Evaluate@Table[N[G1[d, 1, v, 30], 20], {d, 2, 10, 2}], {v, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All] // Quiet


Solution for n=3:
n = 3;
func = (-(((-1 + t^2 σ^4)^(-d/
   2) (-t σ^2 Gamma[d/2] + 
    Sqrt[π] (-1 + t^2 σ^4)^(d/2)
      Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1/2, 1, (3 - d)/2, 1/(
      t^2 σ^4)]) Sec[(d π)/2])/(
 t σ^2 Gamma[d/2])))^n // FunctionExpand
(*Output 4 terms *)

Compute Inverse Laplace Transform for first term :
LaplaceTransform[(-1 + t^2 \[Sigma]^4)^(-3 d/2)
Sec[(d \[Pi])/2]^3, t, v](*Can't compute!*)

InverseMellinTransform[InverseLaplaceTransform[
MellinTransform[(a + A*t^2   σ^4)^(-3  d/2)  Sec[(d  π)/2]^3, A, s, 
Assumptions -> {d > 0, σ > 0, t >= 0}] // PowerExpand, 
t, v], s, A] /. a -> -1 /. A -> 1 // PowerExpand(*Workaround*)

(*((-1)^(-(1/4) - (3 d)/4) I^(-3 d) 2^(
  1/2 - (3 d)/2) Sqrt[π] v^(-1 - 2 (-(1/4) - (3 d)/4)) σ^(4 (-(1/4) - (3 d)/4))
BesselJ[1/2 (-1 + 3 d), -((I v)/σ^2)] Sec[(d π)/
2]^3)/Gamma[(3 d)/2]*)

Compute Inverse Laplace Transform for second term :
InverseLaplaceTransform[(3 Sqrt[π] (-1 + t^2 σ^4)^-d Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1, (
3 - d)/2, 1/(t^2 σ^4)] Sec[(d π)/2]^3)/(
t σ^2 Gamma[3/2 - d/2] Gamma[d/2]), t, v](*Can't compute!*)

InverseMellinTransform[InverseMellinTransform[InverseLaplaceTransform[MellinTransform[(3  Sqrt[π]  (A + t^2  σ^4)^-d  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 
  1, (3 - d)/2, B/(t^2 σ^4)]  Sec[(d π)/2]^3)/(
 t σ^2 Gamma[3/2 - d/2] Gamma[d/2]), {A, B}, {s1, s2}], t, v], s1, A], s2, B](*Can't compute!*)

F1 = InverseLaplaceTransform[MellinTransform[(
3  Sqrt[π]  (A + t^2  σ^4)^-d  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 
 1, (3 - d)/2, B/(t^2 σ^4)]  Sec[(d π)/2]^3)/(
t σ^2 Gamma[3/2 - d/2] Gamma[d/2]), {A, B}, {s1, s2}], t, 
v](*Workround*)

ClearAll[n,m];
Inactivate[Sum[Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n >= 0, 
  Residue[Assuming[m ∈ Integers && m >= 0, 
     Residue[F1*A^(-s1), {s1, -m}]]*B^(-s2), {s2, -n}]] /. 
 A -> -1 /. B -> 1 // PowerExpand, {n, 0, Infinity}, {m, 0, 
Infinity}], Sum](*Look like is the Kampé de Fériet function*)

Compute Inverse Laplace Transform for third term :
F2 = InverseLaplaceTransform[
MellinTransform[(
3  π  (A + t^2  σ^4)^(-d/2)
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1, (3 - d)/2, B/(
  t^2 σ^4)] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1, (3 - d)/2, R/(
  t^2 σ^4)]  Sec[(d π)/2]^3)/(
t^2 σ^4 Gamma[3/2 - d/2]^2 Gamma[d/2]^2), {A, B, R}, {s1, 
 s2, s3}], t, v] // PowerExpand(*Workround*)
ClearAll[n, m, r];

Inactivate[Sum[Assuming[r \[Element] Integers && r >= 0, 
   Residue[Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n >= 0, 
      Residue[Assuming[m \[Element] Integers && m >= 0, 
         Residue[F2*A^(-s1), {s1, -m}]]*B^(-s2), {s2, -n}]]*
     R^(-s3), {s3, -r}]] /. A -> -1 /. B -> 1 /. R -> 1 // 
PowerExpand, {n, 0, Infinity}, {m, 0, Infinity}, {r, 0, 
Infinity}], Sum](*Look like is Srivastava’s General Triple Hypergeometric Series*)

Compute Inverse Laplace Transform for fourth term :
 F3 = InverseLaplaceTransform[MellinTransform[(π^(3/2)
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1, (3 - d)/2, A/(
  t^2 σ^4)]  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1, (3 - d)/2, B/(
  t^2 σ^4)] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1, (3 - d)/2, R/(
  t^2 σ^4)] Sec[(d π)/2]^3)/(
  t^3 σ^6 Gamma[3/2 - d/2]^3 Gamma[d/2]^3), {A, B, R}, {s1, s2, s3}], t, v] // PowerExpand(*Workround*)

  Inactivate[Sum[Assuming[r ∈ Integers && r >= 0, 
   Residue[Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n >= 0, 
      Residue[Assuming[m ∈ Integers && m >= 0, 
         Residue[F3*A^(-s1), {s1, -m}]]*B^(-s2), {s2, -n}]]*
     R^(-s3), {s3, -r}]] /. A -> -1 /. B -> 1 /. R -> 1 // 
  PowerExpand, {n, 0, Infinity}, {m, 0, Infinity}, {r, 0, 
  Infinity}], Sum](*Look like is Srivastava’s General Triple Hypergeometric Series*)

let's put it all together and we have a solution for n=3:
$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (-1)^{-\frac{3 d}{4}-\frac{1}{4}} i^{-3 d} 2^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3 d}{2}} \sigma ^{4 \left(-\frac{3 d}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\right)} v^{-2 \left(-\frac{3 d}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\right)-1} \sec ^3\left(\frac{\pi  d}{2}\right)
   J_{\frac{1}{2} (3 d-1)}\left(-\frac{i v}{\sigma ^2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3 d}{2}\right)}-\\\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum
   }}\underset{m=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{3 (-1)^{m+n} 4^{-n} e^{i (m+n) \pi } \sqrt{\pi } v^{2 d+2 m+2 n} \sigma ^{-2-4 d-4 m-4 n} \Gamma (d+m) \Gamma (1+2 n) \sec
   ^3\left(\frac{d \pi }{2}\right)}{m! n! \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right) \Gamma (d) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}+n\right) \Gamma (1+2 d+2 m+2 n)}+\\\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty
   }{\sum }}\underset{m=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\underset{r=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{3 (-1)^{m+n+r} 4^{-n-r} e^{i \pi  (m+n+r)} \pi  v^{1+d+2 m+2 n+2 r} \sigma ^{-4-2 d-4
   m-4 n-4 r} \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}+m\right) \Gamma (1+2 n) \Gamma (1+2 r) \sec ^3\left(\frac{d \pi }{2}\right)}{m! n! r! \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^3 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}+n\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}+r\right) \Gamma (d+2 (1+m+n+r))}-\\\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\underset{m=0}{\overset{\infty
   }{\sum }}\underset{r=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{(-1)^{2 m+n+r} e^{(m+n+r) (i \pi -2 \log (2))} \pi ^{3/2} v^{2+2 m+2 n+2 r} \sigma ^{-6-4 m-4 n-4 r} \Gamma (1+2 m) \Gamma (1+2
   n) \Gamma (1+2 r) \sec ^3\left(\frac{d \pi }{2}\right)}{m! n! r! \Gamma \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^3 \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}+m\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}+n\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{d}{2}+r\right) \Gamma (3+2 m+2 n+2 r)}$
now all you need to do is express it using the Kampé de Fériet function and Srivastava’s General Triple Hypergeometric Series
FN3[d_, σ_, v_, M_] := ((-1)^(-(1/4) - (3 d)/4) I^(-3 d) 2^(1/2 - (3 d)/2)
Sqrt[π] v^(-1 - 2 (-(1/4) - (3 d)/4)) σ^(
4 (-(1/4) - (3 d)/4))
BesselJ[1/2 (-1 + 3 d), -((I v)/σ^2)] Sec[(d π)/2]^3)/
  Gamma[(3 d)/2] - 
Sum[(3 (-1)^(m + n) 4^-n E^(I (m + n) π) Sqrt[π] v^(
2 d + 2 m + 2 n) σ^(-2 - 4 d - 4 m - 4 n)
 Gamma[d + m] Gamma[1 + 2 n] Sec[(d π)/2]^3)/(
 m! n! Gamma[d/2] Gamma[d] Gamma[3/2 - d/2 + n] Gamma[
 1 + 2 d + 2 m + 2 n]), {n, 0, M}, {m, 0, M}] + 
Sum[(3 (-1)^(m + n + r) 4^(-n - r) E^(I π (m + n + r)) π v^(
1 + d + 2 m + 2 n + 2 r) σ^(-4 - 2 d - 4 m - 4 n - 4 r)
 Gamma[d/2 + m] Gamma[1 + 2 n] Gamma[1 + 2 r] Sec[(d π)/
 2]^3)/(m! n! r! Gamma[d/2]^3 Gamma[3/2 - d/2 + n] Gamma[
 3/2 - d/2 + r] Gamma[d + 2 (1 + m + n + r)]), {n, 0, M}, {m, 0, 
M}, {r, 0, M}] - 
Sum[((-1)^(m + n + r) E^((m + n + r) (I π - 2 Log[2])) π^(
3/2) v^(2 + 2 m + 2 n + 2 r) σ^(-6 - 4 m - 4 n - 4 r)
 Gamma[1 + 2 m] Gamma[1 + 2 n] Gamma[1 + 2 r] Sec[(d π)/
 2]^3)/(m! n! r! Gamma[d/2]^3 Gamma[3/2 - d/2 + m] Gamma[
 3/2 - d/2 + n] Gamma[3/2 - d/2 + r] Gamma[
 3 + 2 m + 2 n + 2 r]), {n, 0, M}, {m, 0, M}, {r, 0, M}]

 Plot[Evaluate@Table[N[FN3[d, 1, v, 20], 20], {d, 2, 10, 2}], {v, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All] // Quiet



Thank you for the response. I am not very familiar with Mellin transforms. Would you have an explanation as to why taking the Mellin transform to the power of n, which I thought represented a multiplicative convolution, taking the Laplace transform of that, and then only taking the inverse Mellin transform and not the inverse Laplace transform works?

@DysonSphere I have a question: does my answer give the correct result? Try: LaplaceTransform[BesselK[a, x], x, s] ==   FullSimplify[   InverseMellinTransform[       LaplaceTransform[MellinTransform[BesselK[a, A*t], A, q], t, s],        q, A] /. A -> 1 // Simplify // FunctionExpand,    Assumptions -> {s > 0, a > 0}]

@DysonSphere .
All computer algebra systems, including Mathematica, are limited in their capabilities. I  taking the Mellin transform because it works and inverse Laplace  transform can't.

All that is built on the sand. E.g. MellinTransform[  Piecewise[{{(2^(3/2 - d/2)*v^((-1 + d)/2)*\[Sigma]^(-1 - d)*        BesselK[(-1 + d)/2, (A*v)/\[Sigma]^2])/(Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[d/2]),      v >= 0}}, 0], A, s, GenerateConditions -> True] results in ConditionalExpression[(2^(-(1/2) - d/2 + s) v^(     1/2 (-1 + d)) (v/\[Sigma]^2)^-s \[Sigma]^(-1 - d)      Gamma[1/4 - d/4 + s/2] Gamma[-(1/4) + d/4 + s/2] UnitStep[      v])/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[d/2]),   Re[d] + 2 Re[s] > 1 &&    Re[d] < 1 + 2 Re[s] && (2 Re[s] < 3 || Arg[v/\[Sigma]^2] < \[Pi])].

@MariuszIwaniuk sadly your answer does not give the correct result. When I simulate the expected result for $n = 1$ and $d = 2,4,6,8, 10$ (as demonstrated in my latest edit above), the result of Table[f[1] /. {d -> c, \[Sigma] -> 1}, {c, 2, 10, 2}] does not result in the same plots as above

@MariuszIwaniuk thank you for the work, would it be possible to elaborate on how you found the solution for n=2 please? To be honest, I have only just recently learned about hypergeometric functions, so I am not very familiar with this whole field and what Lauricella Functions and the extended Kampé de Fériet are, so I will have to do some additional research to understand this domain better. Do you happen to have a good reference good / journal that you would recommend?

Given that the variables are all the same, is there maybe a way that the series could be simplified?

A cardinal edit of an answer (in particular, deleting of a previous answer) is not a good practice. Also the answer from the sky does not make a good impression.

@user64494 My previous answer was wrong, I was supposed to leave it like that. I had inspiration from God, that's why it comes from sky.

@DysonSphere A good reference?  A Google, maybe: https://mathworld.wolfram.com and https://functions.wolfram.com. See REFERENCES below page: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html

Tou wrote "LaplaceTransform[(-1 + t^2 [Sigma]^4)^(-3 d/2)
Sec[(d [Pi])/2]^3, t, v](Can't compute!)". The reason is that this Laplace transform does not exist in some cases. The following works LaplaceTransform[(-1 + t^2  \[Sigma]^4)^(-3  d/2)  Sec[(d  \[Pi])/      2]^3, t, v, Assumptions -> \[Sigma] \[Element] Reals,   GenerateConditions -> True].

The result is ConditionalExpression[  1/Sqrt[\[Pi]]    I^(-3 d) 2^(-(1/2) - (3 d)/2) v^(-(1/2) + (3 d)/2)     Abs[\[Sigma]]^(-1 - 3 d)     Gamma[1 - (3 d)/2] Sec[(d \[Pi])/     2]^3 (\[Pi] BesselI[1/2 (1 - 3 d), v/\[Sigma]^2] +       2 I^(3 d)        BesselK[1/2 (1 - 3 d), v/\[Sigma]^2] - \[Pi] StruveL[        1/2 - (3 d)/2, v/\[Sigma]^2]), Re[d] < 2/3 && Re[v] > 0].

Also LaplaceTransform[(-1 + t^2  \[Sigma]^4)^(-3  d/2)  Sec[(d  \[Pi])/      2]^3, t, v, Assumptions -> Im[\[Sigma]] == -1,   GenerateConditions -> True] results in

ConditionalExpression[  1/Sqrt[\[Pi]]    I^(-3 d) 2^(-(1/2) - (3 d)/2)     v^(-(1/2) + (3 d)/2) (\[Sigma]^4)^(-(1/4) - (3 d)/4)     Gamma[1 - (3 d)/2] Sec[(d \[Pi])/     2]^3 (\[Pi] BesselI[1/2 (1 - 3 d), v/Sqrt[\[Sigma]^4]] +       2 I^(3 d)        BesselK[1/2 (1 - 3 d), v/Sqrt[\[Sigma]^4]] - \[Pi] StruveL[        1/2 - (3 d)/2, v/Sqrt[\[Sigma]^4]]),   Re[\[Sigma]] !=     0 && (Re[\[Sigma]^4] < 0 || \[Sigma]^4 \[NotElement] Reals) &&    Re[v] > 0 && \[Sigma]^2 \[NotElement] Reals] and the same with Assumptions -> Im[\[Sigma]] == 2.

@user64494 Thank you for the additional information for the condition generation and bounds, in my case I would actually need \[Sigma] \[Element] PositiveReals, d \ \[Element] PositiveIntegers, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers , since \[Sigma] represents the standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution, so I do not believe that you can use a complex \[Sigma].

@MariuszIwaniuk thank you for the update and for the steps to solve for n=2 and n=3, this has been a great help. Just a small clarification when you say that the "Exteded version Kampé de Fériet function dosen't exist. It has not yet been formulated for today." Do you mean in Mathematica or in literature in general?

@DysonSphere I was wrong exist  "Exteded version Kampé de Fériet function " for triple variables in literature See: https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/14/12/2502
